# Javascript random quote onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to display a random quote from an array when a button is clicked. The problem is that my code doesn't show a first random quote when I load the page. In other words, this code works but to see the first quote I must press the button. How can I have a first random quote when I load the browser? Thank you!

```
<script language="javascript">
function quotes(){

var aquote = new Array;
aquote[0]="\"Quote 1.\"";
aquote[1]="\"Quote 2.\"";
aquote[2]="\"Quote 3.\""

rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*aquote.length);
document.getElementById("txtbox") .value=aquote[rdmQuote];
}

</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:600px;" readonly></textarea>

<button onClick="quotes()">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuFaa/1/)**

You can call the `quotes` function in order to get the first random quote. However, this should be done once the function can access the dom element. As a result, you are going to want to wait for the dom to render before attempting to access that element. You can do this by attaching the `onload` event to `window` and then having that call the function `quotes`.

```
function quotes(){

 var aquote = new Array;
 aquote[0]="\"Quote 1.\"";
 aquote[1]="\"Quote 2.\"";
 aquote[2]="\"Quote 3.\""

 rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*aquote.length);
 document.getElementById("txtbox") .value=aquote[rdmQuote];
}
window.onload=quotes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function quotes(){

    var aquote = new Array;
    aquote[0]="\"Quote 1.\"";
    aquote[1]="\"Quote 2.\"";
    aquote[2]="\"Quote 3.\""

    rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*aquote.length);
    document.getElementById("txtbox") .value=aquote[rdmQuote];
}

quotes(); // here call that function. just make sure the DOM is ready.
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function quotes() after defining it in the script tag.  If the script tag shows up after the DOM element you're trying to get, you should be fine.  But putting it in a $(document).ready() block would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.onload = quotes;
```

After the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the others have suggested assigning the quotes function to an event handler like onload or onready. This will not always work depending on what other scripts may also be using those event handlers, and whether or not they gracefully redefine the event handlers or overrwrite the event handler.

When I write code such as yours, or answer questions like yours, and I don't know for sure what environment it will be run in, I use either setTimeout or another script placed after the necessary textarea HTML has been defined.

You can use gdoron's answer if you make sure that you place the entire script after the HTML that contains the textarea.

If you cannot use event handlers, and cannot move the script element after the HTML element where it is used, then you can add this line to your code. In practice it should work all the time, but in theory it might fail:

```
setTimeout(quotes, 500);
```

Add that line before your closing script tag and you should be good to go if none of the other methods work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create an array and assign your quote urls

var quotation = new Array();

quotation[0] = "paster your quote url";
quotation[1] = "paster your quote url";
quotation[2] = "paster your quote url";
quotation[3] = "paster your quote url";

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotation.length));
function printquote(){
document.write(quotation[random]);
}

<button onclick="printquote">Get quote</button>
```